# How would you go about a form with 30+ calculation depending on each other

Tags: javascript, date-arithmetic

I have this Excel file with over 30 calculation, but i am having doubts about how to create that on the web.

In excel it is very easy, but on the web it must all be made in javascript, and it is not as easy as reference inputs as in excel where you can just say (C4 + C5 / E9 * 1000).

All the calculations has to be calculated in realtime, so that they can se the final price at the end, without submitting it first.

Since some of the inputs depend on others values, how I see it, the formular must be recalculated a lot of times.

Has anybody done something like this before, and did they do it? Right now I can not seem to find any good javascript libraries which can ease the process.

Answer (score 1):

This is a neat grid plugin for jQuery which supports creating "Excel like" Grids on Webpages.

http://www.trirand.com/blog/

https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Answer (score 0):

Give each input an "id" attribute (will make the use of `getElemetntById` possible). Google for "javascript oninput event".

Answer (score 0):

You want to take an Excel spreadsheet and translate that into javascript code that receives the input variables (the ones you have to fill in Excel) and outputs all of them?

The way to do this is describe each Excel cell as a node in a graph. If cell Y needs cell X to perform a computation, then you must have an edge from node X to node Y.

You must then find a topological ordering for the graph (that is, an order of the cells/nodes such that when you try to compute any cell D you have already computed all the cells it depends on). The algorithm to do this is simple and linear in the size of the graph: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

You can just write javascript code in sequence according to the topological order, and you'll be able to find all the results with having to visit any operation more than once.

Answer (score 0):

There are several js libraries ([AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) is one I enjoy) which offer real-time databinding. If you set up a few input text boxes (NumberA, NumberB), and have some read-only text areas databound to the formulas you need (NumberA + NumberB/10), you might be able to accomplish this without too much stress.

Of course, this assumes you need only one "row" of information- a recreation of Excel is going to be a mite trickier.